# Missing texture in .OBJ model on min3d framwork android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, .obj

I am following this tuttorial:
http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-load-a-3d-obj-model-with-min3d-for-android/

this is my mtl file:

```
    newmtl Texture0
    Ns 20
    d 1
    illum 2
    map_Kd face_eyel_hi.jpg
    Kd 0.7 0.7 0.7
    Ks 0 0 0
    Ka 0 0 0
    newmtl Texture1
    Ns 20
    d 1
   illum 2
   map_Kd face_eyer_hi.jpg
   Kd 0.7 0.7 0.7
   Ks 0 0 0
   Ka 0 0 0
   newmtl Texture2
   Ns 20
     d 1
   illum 2
   map_Kd face_skin_hi.jpg
   Kd 0.7 0.7 0.7
   Ks 0 0 0
   Ka 0 0 0
   newmtl Texture3
   Ns 20
   d 1
   illum 2
   map_Kd face_sock.jpg
   Kd 0.7 0.7 0.7
   Ks 0 0 0
   Ka 0 0 0
```

the obj file is in the last comment in the url i gave above

The texture is always missing can u tell me whats wrong ?

if u want to see the code check the url above.

Answer (score 0):

i found whats wrong ,

the problem is in the tabulation of the mtl file,

just make sure that their is no indentation in the mtl file, and the texture will load perfectly

thank you !