# Missing texture while loading .Obj blender file on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, blender, .obj

i did my own custom 3d object on blender,
its a simple UV Sphere with the earth mape as texture.

after loading it an rendering it on blender the object is appearing with no texture.

this is my mtl file:

```
newmtl Material.001
Ns 96.078431
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd earth.jpg
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
```

i made sure to put everything in place "the earth.jpg" in the res/drawble directory

this is my code to load the obj

```
    IParser myParser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ, getResources(), "com.min3dtest:raw/earth_obj",true);
    myParser.parse();
    faceObject3D = myParser.getParsedObject();
    faceObject3D.position().x = faceObject3D.position().y = faceObject3D.position().z = 0;
    faceObject3D.scale().x = faceObject3D.scale().y = faceObject3D.scale().z = 0.009f; // Depending on the model you will need to change the scale         
    scene.addChild(faceObject3D);
```

guys please help what could be the probelm ??

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [your earlier question about the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585203/missing-texture-in-obj-model-on-min3d-framwork-android)?

Answer (score 0):

Does your texture has a power of 2? (For instance: 1024x512 instead of 1000x512)